# How to not to display image if it doesn't exist in widget

Tags: database, image, yii

I'm using yii cdetail widget for viewing but..I'm wondering how to find a way if the image doesn't exist.

**I'm getting the error: Trying to get property of non-object**

```
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.CDetailView', array(
'data'=>$model,
'attributes'=>array(
    'id',
            'name',
    'keywords',
   array(
    'label'=>'Image',
    'type'=>'raw',
    'value'=>$fileModel->name ? CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/uploads/'.$model->logo_file_id.'/'.$fileModel->file_name.$fileModel->extension,"image_url") : null,
        ),

    'contact_name',
    'description',
    'status',
    'created',

),
)); ?>
```

Can anyone please tell me whats wrong here?

Comment: Assuming that `$model` is always set, it is `$fileModel` being `null` causes the exception. You have to add check if `$fileModel` is set (or maybe even if it is set, check if the file exists on disk).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this..

```
"value"=>'($data->picture !=="") ? CHtml::image(Yii::app()->request->baseurl."/upload/technician/".$data->picture,"",array(\'width\'=>100, \'height\'=>50)) : ""',
```

I Hope it will help you...

Answer (score 1):

In the model you could have a getter method returning the image or the default one if it doesn't exist:

```
public function getImage() {
    $url = Yii::app()->request->baseUrl.'/uploads/'.$this->logo_file_id.'/'.$fileModel->file_name.$fileModel->extension;
    if(file_exists($url)){
        return $url
    }
    //return the default image for example
}
```

Then in your view you'll just do

```
'value'=> CHtml::image($model->Image,"image_url"),
//Note that i'm calling "Image" and not getImage()
```

Of course this code has to be improved since $fileModel won't be defined in the method `getImage` but I don't know what is it's role!

Comment: It is worth to mention that if `$this->logo_file_id` or `$fileModel->file_name` is not set (i.e. there is no image), the getter has to return a path to some "no_image.jpg" file.